# Does PHP's in_array really go through the whole array?

Tags: php, arrays, zend-framework, contain

I stumbled over a few articles (e.g. [this one](http://maettig.com/1397246220)) and infos that suggest PHP's `in_array()` goes through the whole array.

Now there is a possible duplicate of this question here: [How does PHP's in_array function work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37209146/how-does-phps-in-array-function-work) but the OP was obviously satisfied with the copy/paste of the C language function definition and no further description...

My question however is:

#### Does PHP's `in_array()` *really* go through the *whole* array?

I tried to look further and go after the `ZEND_HASH_FOREACH_KEY_VAL`, but then it got a bit confusing:

- [the C-language definition of `php_search_array()`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/array.c) ...  AKA `in_arary()` in PHP
- [Codes of `ZEND_HASH_FOREACH_KEY_VAL` and `ZEND_HASH_FOREAC`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_hash.h)

Only thing I am sure of is that since the ??iteration?? happens on the "C-level" it should be faster than "manual" `foreach`...

Comment: Until it finds a match, yes

Comment: Don't spam tags. This is not related to C.

Comment: @Olaf It may seem like it, but it is in the end an explanation of C framework function code - in C ... do you still have the same opinion? (This question I think is related as much to PHP as it is to using frameworks in C ... there was no intention to spam :) )

Comment: @MarkBaker would you be so kind and provide some more explanation/"proof" please? :)

Comment: The proof is in the source code that you've linked: which part of `for (; _p != _end; _p++) {` are you finding confusing?

Comment: @MarkBaker Well that is obvious iteration :) I ment more the rest, like what is `(_ht)->arData`

Comment: @jave.web: I can read. Just mentioning a C founction is used does not justify the C **language** tag!

Comment: @Olaf Ok, you are telling me explanation of a C language function is not C language related, I see no further discussion here. Thank you for your input though.

Comment: That's just childish behaviour. Your question is actually about the **behaviour**; a specific implementation is not relevant for your question.

Comment: @Olaf If you want to accuse people of childish behaviour, you surely should start with the man in the mirror. Specific implementation is very relevant, if it would be implemented in bricks it surely could have house-like complexity, not a binary one, I know this is ridiculous example, but I am just making the point. Till now you've given me only reasons why to put the C tag back, not why it should stay removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does PHP's in_array really go through the whole array?

TLDR; **No it doesn't.**

The way I read the C implementation:

1. ZEND_HASH_FOREACH_KEY_VAL or rather ZEND_HASH_FOREACH iterates over the array data bucket with a pointer to the current element.
2. The element pointer is assigned to the variable *entry* in *void php_search_array* for each iteration.
3. When a match is found, The PHP list item itself or PHP bool is returned by the engine depending on the *behavior* argument given to the function.

To answer your question:

php_search_array either invokes Zend **RETURN_TRUE** (impl: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_API.h) or sets **RET_VAL** and performs a C return; afterwards. It both cases, C execution breaks out of the iteration of the array if a match is found.

Comment: `iterates over the array data bucket` and what is in the bucket? All array items or some subset?

Comment: That would be all array items. Worst case look up time for in_array() is O(n) where n is the total number of elements. It is basically a simple linear search. But best case is still O(1), given that the first element of the array matches.

Comment: Thank you, you've fully understood the question and explained the last thing to make it complete :)

Comment: BTW: I would add to TLDR, that it does go "step by step" ***until*** it finds the match.